# The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared - mootool script

Tags: firefox, encoding

I just noticed that there is a **warning** message pops up when I view my mootool.js script on FireFox browser.

The warning message is

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
> The document will render with garbled text in some browser
> configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
> US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
> declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
> mark as an encoding signature.

does that mean I have to add a Charset or something? but it is a script!!

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I don't see how that is connected to MooTools...

Comment: this same error message appears on ff when I attempt to get into  https://itunesconnect.apple.com/  to manage my iOS app while on ubuntu 18.04 using  firefox 61.0a1 (2018-05-03) (64-bit)

Answer (score 36):

In your HTML it is a good pratice to provide the encoding like using the following meta like this for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

> Note: if any line between `<head>` and this meta line (Even if it's a
> commented note) problem will remain, so make sure you added meta line
> after `<head>` directly

But your warning that you see may be trigged by one of multiple files. it might not be your HTML document. It might be something in a javascript file or css file. if you page is made of up multiples php files included together it may be only 1 of those files.

I dont think this error has anything to do with mootools. you see this message in your firefox console window. not  mootools script.

maybe you simply need to re-save your html pages using a code editor that lets you specify the correct character encoding.

Answer (score 17):

FireFox is reporting that the response did not even specify the character encoding in the header, eg. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` and not just `Content-Type: text/plain;`.

What web server are you using? Are you sure you are not requesting a non-existing page (404) that responds poorly?

Comment: Can be that the server used is replacing your html with an empty html, on view page source, you wont' find anything in that page except that the server is listening on port, but not actually rendering any html.

Answer (score 12):

Check your URL's protocol.

You will also see this error if you host an encrypted page (https) and open it as plain text (http) in Firefox.

Comment: That’s just wrong, this is an encoding error, not a security error. But your server may specify a default charset in a HTTP header, so maybe that’s where the confusion stems from?

Answer (score 7):

### For HTML 5:

Simply add to your `<head>`

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **ASP.NET Core MVC** project. This error message can be shown then you have the correct `cshtml` file in your `Views` folder but the action is missing in your controller.

Adding the missing action to the controller will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by adding a `slash` at the beginning to my relative path

Answer (score 2):

In my case in **ASP MVC** it was a method in controller that was returning `null` to View because of a wrong `if` statement.

```
if (condition)
{
    return null;
}
```

Condition fixed and I returned View, Problem fixed. There was nothing with encoding but I don't know why that was my error.

```
return View(result); // result is View's model
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error using **Spring Boot** (in Mozilla),

because I was just testing some basic controller -> service -> repository communication by directly returning some entities from the database to the browser (as JSON).

I forgot to put data in the database, so my method wasn't returning anything... and I got this error.

Now that I put some data in my db, it works fine (the error is removed). :D

Comment: In that case it should throw some error message. It shouldn't give this error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in ASP.NET Core. In my case, it was caused by a missing `appsettings.{Environment}.json` file.

I had recently changed the environment to `Production`, but did not have an `appsettings.Production.json` file. The missing file caused a 500 Server Error which resulted in the character encoding browser message.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while working with live server in vs code.

Probably this error was because the the the default path for `"proxyUri"` was `"null"` in settings.json of live server file.

Solution was this was to set `"false"` as value for the `"enable"` key in  `"liveServer.settings.proxy"`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using SQL and they have meta tags there and still the error is shown, this happens because of your connection from .net to SQL.

In you appsettings.json update your connection string to have: `Persist Security Info=True`. So your connection string should look like this:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=[[server]];Initial Catalog=[[db]];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[[user]];Password=[[pass]];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the issue when moving to the next page in a table then clicking a button on the table...an easy fix is calling

```
 $(function () {
      $('#tableid').DataTable();
 });
```

inside document.ready not outside