# React app hosted on heroku goes blank when clicked refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, react-router

I hosted a MERN app which uses webpack on heroku. React Routing works fine on local host. But on heroku, when I click refresh on `/any-path` page is blanked out.

Console shows an error "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Raven</title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/logo.png">
 <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Bootstrap, Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './components/App/App';
import NotFound from './components/App/NotFound';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';



import './styles/styles.scss';

render((
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Home}/>
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

server.js

```
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')));
  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
    res.end();
  });
```

Comment: What's the URL of your heroku app?

Comment: Refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995486

Comment: @AbhinavManchanda Already tried that. I included that meta tag in my html file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a script file inside your `index.html`.

Comment: @Tholle Updated index.html

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the exact same issue.