# file uploding action not get invoke

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC project using Visual Studio 2017 . When i click File upload button it not direct to controller method it directs to a blank page .This page worked as expected Few hours ago nothing changed ,but now im getting  this issue Browser console gives me this error .

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature

.

View code

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">@Localizer["ImportWorkFile"]</h3>
        <h1>@ViewBag.message</h1>
        <form action="@Url.Action("ImportWorkers")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="OrganizationId" value="@Model"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="send" value="true" />
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div>@Localizer["Only"]  <strong>.csv</strong> @Localizer["FileSuported"]</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="importFile" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input id="importFile" name="csvFile" type="file" class="form-control" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="name" value="@Localizer["Send"]" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportWorkers(bool send, long OrganizationId)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Is this added into your page head tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared - mootool script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604466/the-character-encoding-of-the-plain-text-document-was-not-declared-mootool-scr)

Comment: Do you have any code inside that ImportWorkers action method?

Comment: Yes but method not get hit when upload button click

Comment: check with browser console what is the data is getting posted, may be your organizationid is null, and since it is not nullable, it may not find your action method. hope browser console will help you better in this case. thanks

Comment: OrganizationId  is not null , i checked it