# Trying to Send HTML From C Server But Browser Has Issues

Tags: html, c, browser, server

So the I basically copied [Beej's server code](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/server.c) just so I can get an idea of how to create a server. Now I want to send HTML to a browser with CSS styling and anything else through this code. What I think I have to do is send and HTTP response to the browser. In my code I prepare a message that has some HTTP header like this:

```
"HTTP /1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 92\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>\r\n"
```

afterwards I use the send() function to send the data to the client but every time I send the data it looks like this on the webpage:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure what the error is but I tried listening to [what other people have used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604466/the-character-encoding-of-the-plain-text-document-was-not-declared-mootool-scr) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Http 1.1 requires a Host: field. Plus it's http/1.1 without a space.

Comment: @Shawn `Host:` is sent from the client, not the server.

Comment: The space after `HTTP` is probably the problem.